# Graph flow chart of transition from states

Tags: r, plot, flowchart

I'm trying to find a way to graph something like this in R:

[image: Image created with inkscape]

It is a transition between states, I want the boxes to be equal to the population size and the arrows to indicate the size of the transition. I've looked at the [Diagram](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/diagram/vignettes/diagram.pdf) package but it's flow charts seem too crude for this.

1. Is there a better package that allows this?
2. If 1 == FALSE: Is there some other software that is better suited?
3. If 1 & 2 == FALSE: I guess the last resort is grid [rectangles](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/grid/html/grid.roundrect.html) and [bezier curved arrows](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/grid/html/grid.bezier.html), any ideas how to quickly get this off the ground?

Comment: Can you take a look at this http://journal.r-project.org/archive/2012-2/RJournal_2012-2_Sadeghi+Marchetti.pdf . It might be helpful.

Comment: What do you mean by "to[o] crude for this"? `plotmat` fullfills the requirements you give in the text. Of course, if you want fancy-shaped arrows and such, you need to modify the function or write your own.

Comment: @Roland: Yep, I like the fancy arrows and especially I want the thickness to indicate the number of subjects that transition. I also want the box to represent the the number of subjects by it's size and in the examples I didn't see that being the case. Thank you btw for the spelling note

Comment: @Jdbaba: Thank you for the reference, the MM graphs are easily achieved with the diagram package. They are excellent for complex patterns, in my case I have three states before and after, i.e. a very simple, one-way transition. I think this simple graphic would be a nice addition to the text but I guess it's too simple for plotting...

Answer (score 36, accepted):

OK, so I couldn't resist it, I did a plot based upon the grid package as @agstudy suggested. A few things still bother me:

- The bezier arrows don't follow the line but point straight in to the box instead of coming in at an angle.
- I'm not aware of a nice grading option of bezier curves, there seems to be in general little support for gradients in R (most solutions that I've read are about mutliple lines)

## Fixed it

Ok, after a lot of work I finally got it exactly right. The new 0.5.3.0 version of my package has the code for the plot.

[image]

## Old code

Here's the plot:

[image: Example]

And the code:

```
#' A transition plot
#' 
#' This plot purpose is to illustrate how states change before and
#' after. In my research I use it before surgery and after surgery
#' but it can be used in any situation where you have a change from 
#' one state to another
#'  
#' @param transition_flow This should be a matrix with the size of the transitions.
#'  The unit for each cell should be number of observations, row/column-proportions 
#'  will show incorrect sizes. The matrix needs to be square. The best way to generate
#'  this matrix is probably just do a \code{table(starting_state, end_state)}. The rows 
#'  represent the starting positions, while the columns the end positions. I.e. the first
#'  rows third column is the number of observations that go from the first class to the 
#'  third class.
#' @param box_txt The text to appear inside of the boxes. If you need line breaks
#'  then you need to manually add a \\n inside the string. 
#' @param tot_spacing The proportion of the vertical space that is to be left
#'  empty. It is then split evenly between the boxes.
#' @param box_width The width of the box. By default the box is one fourth of
#'  the plot width.
#' @param fill_start_box The fill color of the start boxes. This can either 
#'  be a single value ore a vector if you desire different colors for each 
#'  box. 
#' @param txt_start_clr The text color of the start boxes. This can either 
#'  be a single value ore a vector if you desire different colors for each 
#'  box.
#' @param fill_end_box The fill color of the end boxes. This can either 
#'  be a single value ore a vector if you desire different colors for each 
#'  box.
#' @param txt_end_clr The text color of the end boxes. This can either 
#'  be a single value ore a vector if you desire different colors for each 
#'  box.
#' @param pt The point size of the text
#' @param min_lwd The minimum width of the line that we want to illustrate the
#'  tranisition with. 
#' @param max_lwd The maximum width of the line that we want to illustrate the
#'  tranisition with. 
#' @param lwd_prop_total The width of the lines may be proportional to either the 
#'  other flows from that box, or they may be related to all flows. This is a boolean
#'  parameter that is set to true by default, i.e. relating to all flows.
#' @return void 
#' @example examples/transitionPlot_example.R
#' 
#' @author max
#' @import grid
#' @export
transitionPlot <- function (transition_flow,
                            box_txt = rownames(transition_flow),
                            tot_spacing = 0.2,
                            box_width = 1/4, 
                            fill_start_box = "darkgreen",
                            txt_start_clr = "white",
                            fill_end_box = "steelblue",
                            txt_end_clr = "white",
                            pt=20,
                            min_lwd = 1,
                            max_lwd = 6,
                            lwd_prop_total = TRUE) {
  # Just for convenience
  no_boxes <- nrow(transition_flow)

  # Do some sanity checking of the variables
  if (tot_spacing < 0 ||
        tot_spacing > 1)
    stop("Total spacing, the tot_spacing param,",
      " must be a fraction between 0-1,",
      " you provided ", tot_spacing)

  if (box_width < 0 ||
        box_width > 1)
    stop("Box width, the box_width param,",
      " must be a fraction between 0-1,",
      " you provided ", box_width)

  # If the text element is a vector then that means that 
  # the names are the same prior and after
  if (is.null(box_txt))
    box_txt = matrix("", ncol=2, nrow=no_boxes)
  if (is.null(dim(box_txt)) && is.vector(box_txt))
    if (length(box_txt) != no_boxes)
      stop("You have an invalid length of text description, the box_txt param,",
          " it should have the same length as the boxes, ", no_boxes, ",",
          " but you provided a length of ", length(box_txt))
    else
      box_txt <- cbind(box_txt, box_txt)
  else if (nrow(box_txt) != no_boxes ||
        ncol(box_txt) != 2)
    stop("Your box text matrix doesn't have the right dimension, ", 
         no_boxes, " x 2, it has: ", 
         paste(dim(box_txt), collapse=" x "))


  # Make sure that the clrs correspond to the number of boxes
  fill_start_box <- rep(fill_start_box, length.out=no_boxes)
  txt_start_clr <- rep(txt_start_clr, length.out=no_boxes)
  fill_end_box <- rep(fill_end_box, length.out=no_boxes)
  txt_end_clr <- rep(txt_end_clr, length.out=no_boxes)

  if(nrow(transition_flow) != ncol(transition_flow))
    stop("Invalid input array, the matrix is not square but ",
      nrow(transition_flow), " x ", ncol(transition_flow))

  # Set the proportion of the start/end sizes of the boxes
  prop_start_sizes <- rowSums(transition_flow)/sum(transition_flow)
  prop_end_sizes <- colSums(transition_flow)/sum(transition_flow)

  if (sum(prop_end_sizes) == 0)
    stop("You can't have all empty boxes after the transition")

  getBoxPositions <- function (no, side){
    empty_boxes <- ifelse(side == "left", 
      sum(prop_start_sizes==0), 
      sum(prop_end_sizes==0))

    # Calculate basics
    space <- tot_spacing/(no_boxes-1-empty_boxes)

    # Do the y-axis
    ret <- list(height=(1-tot_spacing)*ifelse(side == "left", 
                                              prop_start_sizes[no], 
                                              prop_end_sizes[no]))
    if (no == 1){
      ret$top <- 1
    }else{
      ret$top <- 1 - 
        ifelse(side == "left", 
               sum(prop_start_sizes[1:(no-1)]), 
               sum(prop_end_sizes[1:(no-1)])) * (1-tot_spacing) -
        space*(no-1)
    }
    ret$bottom <- ret$top - ret$height
    ret$y <- mean(c(ret$top, ret$bottom))

    ret$y_exit <- rep(ret$y, times=no_boxes)
    ret$y_entry_height <- ret$height/3
    ret$y_entry <- seq(to=ret$y-ret$height/6,
                       from=ret$y+ret$height/6,
                       length.out=no_boxes)

    # Now the x-axis
    if (side == "right"){
      ret$left <- 1-box_width
      ret$right <- 1
    }else{
      ret$left <- 0
      ret$right <- box_width
    }

    txt_margin <- box_width/10
    ret$txt_height <- ret$height - txt_margin*2
    ret$txt_width <- box_width - txt_margin*2

    ret$x <- mean(c(ret$left, ret$right))

    return(ret)
  }

  plotBoxes <- function (no_boxes, width, txt, 
    fill_start_clr, fill_end_clr, 
    lwd=2, line_col="#000000") {

    plotBox <- function(bx, bx_txt, fill){
      grid.roundrect(y=bx$y, x=bx$x, 
        height=bx$height, width=width, 
        gp = gpar(lwd=lwd, fill=fill, col=line_col))

      if (bx_txt != ""){
        grid.text(bx_txt,y=bx$y, x=bx$x, 
          just="centre", 
          gp=gpar(col=txt_start_clr, fontsize=pt))
      }
    }

    for(i in 1:no_boxes){
      if (prop_start_sizes[i] > 0){
        bx_left <- getBoxPositions(i, "left")
        plotBox(bx=bx_left, bx_txt = txt[i, 1], fill=fill_start_clr[i])
      }

      if (prop_end_sizes[i] > 0){
        bx_right <- getBoxPositions(i, "right")
        plotBox(bx=bx_right, bx_txt = txt[i, 2], fill=fill_end_clr[i])
      }
    }
  }

  # Do the plot
  require("grid")
  plot.new()
  vp1 <- viewport(x = 0.51, y = 0.49, height=.95, width=.95)
  pushViewport(vp1)

  shadow_clr <- rep(grey(.8), length.out=no_boxes)
  plotBoxes(no_boxes, 
            box_width, 
            txt = matrix("", nrow=no_boxes, ncol=2), # Don't print anything in the shadow boxes
            fill_start_clr = shadow_clr, 
            fill_end_clr  = shadow_clr,
            line_col=shadow_clr[1])
  popViewport()

  vp1 <- viewport(x = 0.5, y = 0.5, height=.95, width=.95)
  pushViewport(vp1)
  plotBoxes(no_boxes, box_width, 
            txt = box_txt,
            fill_start_clr = fill_start_box, 
            fill_end_clr  = fill_end_box)

  for (i in 1:no_boxes){
    bx_left <- getBoxPositions(i, "left")
    for (flow in 1:no_boxes){
      if (transition_flow[i,flow] > 0){
        bx_right <- getBoxPositions(flow, "right")

        a_l <- (box_width/4)
        a_angle <- atan(bx_right$y_entry_height/(no_boxes+.5)/2/a_l)*180/pi
        if (lwd_prop_total)
          lwd <- min_lwd + (max_lwd-min_lwd)*transition_flow[i,flow]/max(transition_flow)
        else
          lwd <- min_lwd + (max_lwd-min_lwd)*transition_flow[i,flow]/max(transition_flow[i,])

        # Need to adjust the end of the arrow as it otherwise overwrites part of the box
        # if it is thick
        right <- bx_right$left-.00075*lwd
        grid.bezier(x=c(bx_left$right, .5, .5, right), 
                    y=c(bx_left$y_exit[flow], bx_left$y_exit[flow], 
                        bx_right$y_entry[i], bx_right$y_entry[i]), 
                    gp=gpar(lwd=lwd, fill="black"),
                    arrow=arrow(type="closed", angle=a_angle, length=unit(a_l, "npc")))
        # TODO: A better option is probably bezierPoints

      }
    }
  }
  popViewport()
}
```

And the example was generated with:

```
# Settings
no_boxes <- 3
# Generate test setting
transition_matrix <- matrix(NA, nrow=no_boxes, ncol=no_boxes)
transition_matrix[1,] <- 200*c(.5, .25, .25)
transition_matrix[2,] <- 540*c(.75, .10, .15)
transition_matrix[3,] <- 340*c(0, .2, .80)

transitionPlot(transition_matrix,  
  box_txt = c("First", "Second", "Third"))
```

I've also added this to my [Gmisc-package](http://gforge.se/gmisc/). Enjoy!

Comment: @agstudy: See the new version of the plot. Now it's exactly the way I want it, almost like a graph pro :-D

Comment: @MaxGordon if I have two transition matrices, say from A to B and then from B to C. Can I have a transition plot like 
A >> B >> C ?

Comment: @darkage: I've just posted an answer to your question on the package homepage in the comments: http://gforge.se/packages/

Comment: @darkage: I'm trying to implement a function that can do this, you can fin it in the transitionClass branch: develop::install_github("gforge/Gmist", "transitionClass") I should have it fully cleared for CRAN within a month or two - check out the vignette for how to use it

Comment: Awesome package, but it would be greater whether it would support non-square matrices of input data in the future. For instance from A,B,C states to A,B,C,D,E assuming that from D and E there is no transition to any other state. In the current implementation I get "Invalid input array, the matrix is not square"

Comment: Have you tried to just set the value to 0? Categories should be allowed to appear

Answer (score 7):

This is just to show that `plotmat` can be used for this:

```
library(diagram)

M  <- matrix(nrow = 4, ncol = 4, byrow = TRUE, data = 0)
C <- M
A <- M
M[2, 1] <- "f11" 
M[4, 1] <- "f12" 
M[2, 3] <- "f21" 
M[4, 3] <- "f22"
C[4, 1] <- -0.1
C[2, 3] <- 0.1
A[2, 1] <- A[2, 3] <- A[4, 3] <-4
A[4, 1] <-  8

col   <- M
col[] <- "red"
col[2, 1] <- col[4, 1] <- "blue"
plotmat(M, pos = c(2, 2), curve = C, name = c(1,1,2,2),
        box.size=c(0.05,0.03,0.03,0.05), box.prop = 2,
        arr.lwd=A,
        lwd = 1, box.lwd = 2, box.cex = 1, cex.txt = 0.8, 
        arr.lcol = col, arr.col = col, box.type = "rect",
        lend=3)
```

[image]

Some fine-tuning and possibly modifying the function should give you the graph you want.

Comment: Thanks that's actually pretty close to what I want. I'll mark this as the answer unless someone proposes an even closer alternative the coming days. One thing that have in my mind is to have the boxes closer to each other... but I guess this is good enough.

Comment: After some tweaking I'm actually almost where I want to be. Gets messy with three boxes which is my final destination but I guess if I want it more control I need to write the curves myself. I just figured that this would be "super-easy" with the right package as you see this kind of graphics in the newspapers etc.

Comment: Just wanted to let you know that I implemented my own version of the plot. It is still not perfect but good enough. I'll leave your answer checked though as you were rather close to what I wanted.

Answer (score 4):

My answer is just a proof of concept to  demonstrate the feasibility of this plot using `grid` and `bezier`. I use `lattice` to plot the scene and then `grid` package in the `native`. It is just a start, I think you can easily complete it.

[image]

```
library(grid)
library(lattice)

dat <- data.frame(x=c(1,1,2,2),
                  y=c(1,2,1,2),
                  weight=c(2,1,1,2),
                  text=c('B','A','B','A'))
cols <- colorRampPalette(c("grey", "green"))(nrow(dat))
xyplot(y~x,data=dat,groups=weight,
       xlim=extendrange(dat$x,f=1),
       ylim=extendrange(dat$y,f=1),
       panel=function(x,y,groups,...){
         lapply(seq_along(x),function(i){
         grid.roundrect(x[i],y[i],
                        width=.5, 
                        height=.5*groups[i],
                        gp=gpar(fill=cols[i],lwd=5,col='blue'),
                        def='native')
         grid.text(x[i],y[i],label=dat$text[i],
                    gp=gpar(cex=5,col='white'),
                   def='native')
        })
         xx <- c(x[1]+0.25, x[1]+0.25, x[3]-0.25, x[3]-0.25)
         yy <- c(y[1], y[1], y[3], y[3])
         grid.bezier(xx, yy,
                     gp=gpar(lwd=3, fill="black"),
                     arrow=arrow(type="closed"),
                     def='native')
         xx <- c(x[1]+0.25, 1, 2, x[4]-0.25)
         yy <- c(y[1], 2, 1, y[4])
         grid.bezier(xx, yy,
                     gp=gpar(lwd=3, fill="black"),
                     arrow=arrow(type="closed",
                                 length=unit(0.5, "inches")),
                     def='native')
         xx <- c(x[2]+0.25, x[2]+0.25, x[4]-0.25, x[4]-0.25)
         yy <- c(y[2], y[2], y[4], y[4])
         grid.bezier(xx, yy,
                     gp=gpar(lwd=3, fill="black"),
                     arrow=arrow(type="closed",
                                 length=unit(0.5, "inches")),
                     def='native')

         })
```

Comment: Thanks! Looks like a good starting point. Not sure why you put it inside the lattice, there's no need for the axis...

Comment: @MaxGordon I Know no need for the axis...but otherwise you need to do scaling manually...

Comment: Ok, although I'll probably try to implement without the lattice - I've done some basic grid stuff and it shouldn't be that difficult. I'm not sure how to structure the input-data, there are start populations and then flows from these - perhaps a "wide" formatted data frame would be the best. Your example has the endpoint size if I understand it correctly, this does not translate to width of the bezier curve's lwd parameter... I'll check your answer in a few days just to make sure that no one has my dream function ready before I start developing my own.

Comment: Just wanted to let you know that I implemented the idea, see my answer. A few details that would be nice but it does the job that I need it to do.

Answer (score 0):

Very old post but part of the issue is terminology.  Once you know what to call something it is much easier to figure out how to represent the data.  These charts are  [Sankey Diagrams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sankey_diagram)

I personally like [Mike Bostock's D3js library](https://bost.ocks.org/mike/sankey/) to make these diagrams but R can do them as well.

To do this in R see this [Stack Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19730604/visualize-in-r-flow-from-one-set-of-objects-to-another) or [R-Blogger](https://www.r-bloggers.com/creating-custom-sankey-diagrams-using-r/) post