# igraph in R not working with number labels

Tags: r, igraph

I am using code from this post: [Order of treechart entries not correct in R igraph package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24948003/order-of-flowchart-treemap-entries-not-correct-in-r-igraph-package/24950271)

The code does not work if labels are all / mostly numeric:

```
111
    222
    333
        99
        1010
    44
    55
    66
        1111
            1313
            1414
            1515
    77
    88
        1212
```

Following is the error:

```
Error in if (vr[1] == vr[2]) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In mean.default(sapply(nb, function(x) calcypos(g, x))) :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
2: In mean.default(sapply(nb, function(x) calcypos(g, x))) :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
3: In mean.default(sapply(nb, function(x) calcypos(g, x))) :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
4: In mean.default(sapply(nb, function(x) calcypos(g, x))) :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
5: In mean.default(sapply(nb, function(x) calcypos(g, x))) :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
6: In mean.default(sapply(nb, function(x) calcypos(g, x))) :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
7: In mean.default(sapply(nb, function(x) calcypos(g, x))) :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
8: In mean.default(sapply(nb, function(x) calcypos(g, x))) :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
9: In mean.default(sapply(nb, function(x) calcypos(g, x))) :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
10: In mean.default(sapply(nb, function(x) calcypos(g, x))) :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
>
```

The 'edges' dataframe in code is being made all right (I checked with print(edges)). 
How can I solve this problem? Thanks for your help.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. The word "label" does not even appear in the cited post.

Comment: By labels I meant 111, 222, 333, 99 etc which should appear on the chart as AAA, BBB etc appeared on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24948003/order-of-flowchart-treemap-entries-not-correct-in-r-igraph-package/24950271

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would write this as a comment, but that does not allow structured code. Numbers as labels work fine in igraph:

```
library(igraph)
g <- graph.ring(9)
V(g)$label <- as.character(seq(111, 999, by=111))
plot(g)
```

[image]

Maybe you are adding vertex names, and not converting them the characters? It you specify vertices as numbers (i.e. of mode `numeric`), then igraph treats them as numeric vertex id, not as symbolic vertex names.

Anyway, whatever you want to use as label for plotting, assign it as the `label` vertex attribute.

Comment: Converting all entries to characters corrected the problem. Thanks.