# In R - How do you make transition charts with the Gmisc package?

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, gmisc

I've been trying to make a graph that looks like this (but nicer)

[image: Rudimentary Flow Chart]

based on what I found in [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16112162/graph-flow-chart-of-transition-from-states) using the `transitionPlot()` function from the `Gmisc`package.

However, I can't get my `transition_matrix` right and I also can't seem to plot the different state classes in separate third column.

My data is based on the symptomatic improvement of patients following surgery. The numbers in the boxes are the number of patients in each "state" pre vs. post surgery. Please note the `(LVAD)` is not a necessity.

The data for this plot is this called `df` and is as follows

```
dput(df)
structure(list(StudyID = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 
7L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L), .Label = c("P1", "P2", "P3", 
"P4", "P5", "P6", "P7"), class = "factor"), MeasureTime = structure(c(2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("Postoperative", 
"Preoperative"), class = "factor"), NYHA = c(3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L)), .Names = c("StudyID", 
"MeasureTime", "NYHA"), row.names = c(NA, -14L), class = "data.frame")
```

I've made a plot in `ggplot2` that looked like this

[image: ggplot2 image]

but my supervisor didn't like it, because I had to `jitter`the lines so that they didn't overlap and so one could see what was happening with each patient and thus the points/lines aren't exactly lined up with the y-axis.

So I was wondering if anyone had an idea, how I'd be able to do this using the `Gmisc` package making what seems to me to be a `transitionPlot`.

Your help and time is much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: I dont think `transitionPlot` will work as you want due to the zero cells in your transition matrix - they wont show as the boxes are scaled to the counts

Comment: That kept on coming up as an error when I entered the zeros into the matrix...good point!

Comment: Interesting idea, adding a starter/end text-column should be rather easy although you need to know a little about the grid package in order to get it to work and I guess it would require the boxes to have fixed sizes. It is a good suggestion, not sure if I'll find the time to implement it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using your sample `df` data, here are some pretty low-level plotting function that can re-create your sample image. It should be straigtforward to customize however you like

First, make sure pre comes before post

```
df$MeasureTime<-factor(df$MeasureTime, levels=c("Preoperative","Postoperative"))
```

then define some plot helper functions

```
textrect<-function(x,y,text,width=.2) {
    rect(x-width, y-width, x+width, y+width)
    text(x,y,text)
}
connect<-function(x1,y1,x2,y2, width=.2) {
    segments(x1+width,y1,x2-width,y2)   
}
```

now draw the plot

```
plot.new()
par(mar=c(0,0,0,0))
plot.window(c(0,4), c(0,4))

with(unique(reshape(df, idvar="StudyID", timevar="MeasureTime", v.names="NYHA", direction="wide")[,-1]), 
    connect(2,NYHA.Preoperative,3,NYHA.Postoperative)
)
with(as.data.frame(with(df, table(NYHA, MeasureTime))), 
    textrect(as.numeric(MeasureTime)+1,as.numeric(as.character(NYHA)), Freq)
)

text(1, 1:3, c("I","II","III"))
text(1:3, 3.75, c("NYHA","Pre-Op","Post-Op"))
text(3.75, 2, "(LVAD)")
```

which results in

[image]

Comment: Thanks MrFlick - once again a great answer from you! I'll rate this as an answer, as it effectively does what I want, but I'd still be intrigued to find out how one can do it with `Gmisc` too! I'm trying to break down your code in my head though, so that I can modify it. `textrect` draws the rectangles+text, `connect` draws the connections. But why did you have to `reshape` the `df` into a wide format? And how do you actually command the right connections of the boxes, i.e. that the zero boxes don't get connected?

Comment: I reshape into wide format to match up the pre and post op values for an particular study ID. This tells me which nodes need to be connected.