# An up-to-date method for plotting a transition probability matrix?

Tags: r, matrix, plot, shiny, markov-chains

I'm trying to find an easy, up-to-date way to plot transition matrices. Could someone please recommend a method or package? I found advice on Stack, but the posts are very old, or the referenced packages no longer exist (such as in the Oct 23, 2015 answer to post [R transition plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28329559/r-transition-plot)).

Note that my transition matrices are dynamic: depending on user inputs, the number of states and the to/from periods vary based on the composition of the underlying data. So going into the code and manually adjusting box/arrow sizes won't help much.

I've been leaning towards the Apr 20, 2013 answer to [Graph flow chart of transition from states](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16112162/graph-flow-chart-of-transition-from-states), using the Diagram package, but I wonder if there's a more up-to-date method.

I don't need anything too complicated. I like the type of plot shown in this image (I believe generated via the package that no longer exists in the above referenced post, "MmgraphR"):

[image]

Or this simpler form works for me too:

[image]

Below is a stripped-down version of code I've been using to generate transitions:

```
library(DT)
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(htmltools)
library(data.table)

data <- 
  data.frame(
    ID = c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3),
    Period = c(1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3),
    Values = c(5, 10, 15, 0, 2, 4, 3, 6, 9),
    State = c("X0","X1","X2","X0","X2","X0", "X2","X1","X9")
  )

numTransit <- function(x, from=1, to=3){
  setDT(x)
  unique_state <- unique(x$State)
  all_states <- setDT(expand.grid(list(from_state = unique_state, to_state = unique_state)))
  dcast(x[, .(from_state = State[from], 
              to_state = State[to]), 
          by = ID]
        [,.N, c("from_state", "to_state")]
        [all_states,on = c("from_state", "to_state")], 
        to_state ~ from_state, value.var = "N"
  )
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(tags$style(".datatables .display {margin-left: 0;}")), 
  h4(strong("Base data frame:")), 
  tableOutput("data"),
  h4(strong("Transition table inputs:")),
  numericInput("transFrom", "From period:", 1, min = 1, max = 3),
  numericInput("transTo", "To period:", 2, min = 1, max = 3),
  h4(strong("Output transition table:")), 
  DTOutput("resultsDT"),
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  results <- 
    reactive({
      results <- numTransit(data, input$transFrom, input$transTo) %>% 
        replace(is.na(.), 0) %>%
        bind_rows(summarise_all(., ~(if(is.numeric(.)) sum(.) else "Sum")))
      results <- cbind(results, Sum = rowSums(results[,-1]))
      
    # Express results as percentages:
      results %>% 
        mutate(across(-1, ~ .x / .x[length(.x)])) %>% 
        replace(is.na(.), 0) %>% 
        mutate(across(-1, scales::percent_format(accuracy = 0.1)))
    })
 
  output$data <- renderTable(data)
  
  output$resultsDT <- renderDT(server=FALSE, {
    datatable(
      data = results(),
      rownames = FALSE,
      container = tags$table(
        tags$thead(
          tags$tr(
            tags$th(rowspan = 2,sprintf('To state where end period = %s', input$transTo)),
            tags$th(colspan = 10,sprintf('From state where initial period = %s',input$transFrom))),
          tags$tr(mapply(tags$th, colnames(results())[-1], SIMPLIFY = FALSE))
        )
      ),
    )
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After researching the options, all I could find were the `Gmisc` and `diagram` packages for plotting transition matrices. The `Gmisc` package is very visually appealing though it doesn't facilitate the showing of transit values. `Diagram` package is less visually appealing but easily facilitates the showing of transition values - though to show the **From** states on the left-side of the plot and the **To** states on the right-side of the plot, I had to use a for-loop and other code gyrations to double the size of the matrix and fill in the matrix values skipping rows/columns. Since the transition matrices this code is intended for measure 8 x 8 or more, there would be too many numbers to present in a plot. Therefore I'll use `Gmisc` in the fuller code this post is intended for; the arrows thicken/narrow to represent transition volumes and the user can easily access the transition matrix table with it's >= 64 values. BTW I spent no time making these plots prettier.

Here's the OP code modified to show both plots:

```
library(DT)
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(htmltools)
library(data.table)
# Add two packages for plotting transitions in different manners:
  library(diagram)
  library(Gmisc)

data <- 
  data.frame(
    ID = c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3),
    Period = c(1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3),
    Values = c(5, 10, 15, 0, 2, 4, 3, 6, 9),
    State = c("X0","X1","X2","X0","X2","X0", "X2","X1","X9")
  )

numTransit <- function(x, from=1, to=3){
  setDT(x)
  unique_state <- unique(x$State)
  all_states <- setDT(expand.grid(list(from_state = unique_state, to_state = unique_state)))
  dcast(x[, .(from_state = State[from], 
              to_state = State[to]), 
          by = ID]
        [,.N, c("from_state", "to_state")]
        [all_states,on = c("from_state", "to_state")], 
        to_state ~ from_state, value.var = "N"
  )
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(tags$style(".datatables .display {margin-left: 0;}")), 
  h4(strong("Transition table inputs:")),
  numericInput("transFrom", "From period:", 1, min = 1, max = 3),
  numericInput("transTo", "To period:", 2, min = 1, max = 3),
  h4(strong("Output transition table:")), 
  DTOutput("resultsDT"),
  h4(strong("Transition plot using Gmisc package:")), 
  plotOutput("resultsPlot1"),
  h4(strong("Transition plot using diagram package:")),
  plotOutput("resultsPlot2")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  results <- 
    reactive({
      results <- numTransit(data, input$transFrom, input$transTo) %>% 
        replace(is.na(.), 0) %>%
        bind_rows(summarise_all(., ~(if(is.numeric(.)) sum(.) else "Sum")))
      results <- cbind(results, Sum = rowSums(results[,-1]))
      results %>% 
        mutate(across(-1, ~ .x / .x[length(.x)])) %>% 
        replace(is.na(.), 0) %>% 
        mutate(across(-1, scales::percent_format(accuracy = 0.1)))
    })
 
# extractResults below used for both Gmisc and diagram plots:
  extractResults <- 
    reactive({
      extractResults <- 
        data.frame(lapply(results()[1:nrow(results())-1,2:nrow(results())], 
                          function(x) as.numeric(sub("%", "", x))/100))
      row.names(extractResults) <- colnames(extractResults) 
      t(as.matrix(extractResults))
      })
  
# M below used only for diagram plots; extractResults matrix must be doubled in size
  M <-
    reactive({
      M <- matrix(nrow = nrow(extractResults())*2, ncol = ncol(extractResults())*2, byrow = TRUE, data = 0)
      
      for (i in 1:(nrow(extractResults()))){
        for (j in 1: ncol(extractResults()))
        {M[i*2-1,j*2] <- extractResults()[i,j]
        }}
      
      t(M)
    })
  
  output$resultsDT <- renderDT(server=FALSE, {
    datatable(
      data = results(),
      rownames = FALSE,
      container = tags$table(
        tags$thead(
          tags$tr(
            tags$th(rowspan = 2,sprintf('To state where end period = %s', input$transTo)),
            tags$th(colspan = 10,sprintf('From state where initial period = %s',input$transFrom))),
          tags$tr(mapply(tags$th, colnames(results())[-1], SIMPLIFY = FALSE))
        )
      ),
    )
  })
  
  output$resultsPlot1 <- # transition plot using Gmisc package
    renderPlot({
      suppressWarnings(
        transitionPlot(extractResults(),
                       tot_spacing = 0.01,
                       fill_start_box = "#8DA0CB",
                       fill_end_box = "#FFFF00",
                       txt_end_clr ="#000000"
        )
      )  
    })
    
  output$resultsPlot2 <- # transition plot using diagram package
    renderPlot({
      plotmat(M(), 
              pos = rep(2,times = nrow(extractResults())),
              name = rep(colnames(extractResults()), each = 2),
              curve = 0, # the closer to 1 the more arced the curve
              arr.width = 0.3, # the greater the nbr the larger the arrowhead
              lwd = 1, 
              box.lwd = 2, 
              cex.txt = 0.8, 
              box.size = 0.1, 
              box.type = "square", 
              box.prop = 0.25
      )
    })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

And in the image below you can see the two types of transition plots rendered by the above code:

[image]