# How to change row names of reactive data frame rendered in Shiny?

Tags: r, dataframe, shiny, shiny-reactivity

I'm in the process of rendering a transition plot. In order to get there with the below reproducible code, I'm subsetting data frame `results()` (shown as the first rendered table in Shiny when running the code) and creating new data frame `extractResults()` (shown as the 2nd table when running the code). I'm trying to set the row names of `extractResults()` the same as it's column names but can't quite get it to work.

Easy to do in base R with `rownames(x) <- colnames(x)`, where x is the data frame, but I can't get this to work in Shiny. Must be some other trick to use when dealing with reactivity. The image at the bottom better explains.

The commented-out line in the code shows one of my attempts to do this.

Reproducible code:

```
library(DT)
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)

data <- 
  data.frame(
    ID = c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3),
    Period = c(1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3),
    Values = c(5, 10, 15, 0, 2, 4, 3, 6, 9),
    State = c("X0","X1","X2","X0","X2","X0", "X2","X1","X9")
  )

numTransit <- function(x, from=1, to=3){
  setDT(x)
  unique_state <- unique(x$State)
  all_states <- setDT(expand.grid(list(from_state = unique_state, to_state = unique_state)))
  dcast(x[, .(from_state = State[from], 
              to_state = State[to]), 
          by = ID]
        [,.N, c("from_state", "to_state")]
        [all_states,on = c("from_state", "to_state")], 
        to_state ~ from_state, value.var = "N"
  )
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(tags$style(".datatables .display {margin-left: 0;}")), 
  h4(strong("Transition table inputs:")),
  numericInput("transFrom", "From period:", 1, min = 1, max = 3),
  numericInput("transTo", "To period:", 2, min = 1, max = 3),
  h4(strong("Output transition table:")), 
  DTOutput("resultsDT"),
  h4(strong("Extract of above transition table:")), 
  tableOutput("resultsPlot")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  results <- 
    reactive({
      results <- numTransit(data, input$transFrom, input$transTo) %>% 
        replace(is.na(.), 0) %>%
        bind_rows(summarise_all(., ~(if(is.numeric(.)) sum(.) else "Sum")))
      results <- cbind(results, Sum = rowSums(results[,-1]))
      results %>% 
        mutate(across(-1, ~ .x / .x[length(.x)])) %>% 
        replace(is.na(.), 0) %>% 
        mutate(across(-1, scales::percent_format(accuracy = 0.1)))
    })
  
  extractResults <- 
    reactive({
      extractResults <- 
        data.frame(lapply(results()[1:nrow(results())-1,2:nrow(results())], 
                          function(x) as.numeric(sub("%", "", x))/100))
      # extractResults <- row.names(extractResults) <- colnames(extractResults)
    })
  
  output$data <- renderTable(data)
  
  output$resultsDT <- renderDT(server=FALSE, {datatable(data = results())})
  
  output$resultsPlot <- renderTable({extractResults()})
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

Comment: Replace your commented line with `extractResults %>% add_column(Row=colnames(extractResults), .before=1)` .  And add `library(tibble)` at the head of your code.

Comment: Or, replace your commented line with `row.names(extractResults) <- colnames(extractResults); extractResults` (on two lines: remember, reactives need to return something!) and change your `output$resultsPlot` to `output$resultsPlot <- renderTable({extractResults()}, rownames=TRUE)`.  [And, I'd change the `outputId` too: it's not a good idea to use `xxxxPlot` as the id of something you create with `renderTable`...]

Comment: Hi Limey, thanks for setting me straight. I opted for the 2nd recommendation, because otherwise I'd have to de-tibble the resulting data. My main lessons are (a) don't forget extractResults in a separate line since reactives need to return something, and (b) don't forget rownames = TRUE in renderTable. Through repetition I'll remember this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question/solution was used to complete the answer to this related post: [An up-to-date method for plotting a transition probability matrix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71937096/an-up-to-date-method-for-plotting-a-transition-probability-matrix)

Below is the OP code revised to reflect Limey's solution posited in his 2nd comment above:

```
library(DT)
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)

data <- 
  data.frame(
    ID = c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3),
    Period = c(1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3),
    Values = c(5, 10, 15, 0, 2, 4, 3, 6, 9),
    State = c("X0","X1","X2","X0","X2","X0", "X2","X1","X9")
  )

numTransit <- function(x, from=1, to=3){
  setDT(x)
  unique_state <- unique(x$State)
  all_states <- setDT(expand.grid(list(from_state = unique_state, to_state = unique_state)))
  dcast(x[, .(from_state = State[from], 
              to_state = State[to]), 
          by = ID]
        [,.N, c("from_state", "to_state")]
        [all_states,on = c("from_state", "to_state")], 
        to_state ~ from_state, value.var = "N"
  )
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(tags$style(".datatables .display {margin-left: 0;}")), 
  h4(strong("Transition table inputs:")),
  numericInput("transFrom", "From period:", 1, min = 1, max = 3),
  numericInput("transTo", "To period:", 2, min = 1, max = 3),
  h4(strong("Output transition table:")), 
  DTOutput("resultsDT"),
  h4(strong("Extract of above transition table:")), 
  tableOutput("resultsPlot")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  results <- 
    reactive({
      results <- numTransit(data, input$transFrom, input$transTo) %>% 
        replace(is.na(.), 0) %>%
        bind_rows(summarise_all(., ~(if(is.numeric(.)) sum(.) else "Sum")))
      results <- cbind(results, Sum = rowSums(results[,-1]))
      results %>% 
        mutate(across(-1, ~ .x / .x[length(.x)])) %>% 
        replace(is.na(.), 0) %>% 
        mutate(across(-1, scales::percent_format(accuracy = 0.1)))
    })
  
  extractResults <- 
    reactive({
      extractResults <- 
        data.frame(lapply(results()[1:nrow(results())-1,2:nrow(results())], 
                          function(x) as.numeric(sub("%", "", x))/100))
      row.names(extractResults) <- colnames(extractResults) # << Limey fix
      extractResults # << Limey fix
    })
  
  output$data <- renderTable(data)
  
  output$resultsDT <- renderDT(server=FALSE, {datatable(data = results())})
  
  output$resultsPlot <- renderTable({extractResults()}, 
                                    rownames=TRUE # << Limey fix
                                    )

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```